# Synonymize [restful-architecture] into [rest]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I don't have enough votes to request a synonym from  [restful-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restful-architecture) into [rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest). Can someone make this happen?

Comment: Nobody does.  Propose a synonym instead.

Comment: @HansPassant i can't hence this post.

Comment: Nick Larsen did this a few years back.